# не работает -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

Tags: html, css, webkit

Пытаюсь обрезать текст и добавить троеточие в конце, решил воспользоваться данным методом, но в инспекторе элементов нету правила -webkit-box-orient: vertical;, причем если вставить в инспектор вручную, то все работает. Запускал без сброщиков, не помогло, отключал все расширения в браузере, тоже. Приложил скрин инспектора ниже

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 2; 
display: -webkit-box; 
-webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
overflow: hidden;
```

Ошибки копипаста тоже не вижу, мой css

```
.project__item-title {
    font-family: 'Noah', sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .project__item-title точку в начале имени класса потеряли?

Comment: @Konst нет, просто скопировал неудачно. Я приложил скрин инспектора-кода, где есть все свойства кроме  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

Comment: !important не пробовали добавить?

Comment: @Konst пробовал, не помогло

Comment: @Konst Если я его вручную в инспектор пропишу, то правило сработает, но по пути от редактора до браузера где-то теряется.

Comment: используете scss? проверьте правила , он иногда -webkit выкидывает

Comment: @Konst я пробовал запустить с обычным css и ничего, в редакторе есть, а в браузере нет

Comment: @Konst вы были правы, в минифицированном css этого свойства нет, только в обычном css. Значит проблема во время минификации